# If $a,b\in G$ and $ab=ba$, prove $(ab)^{|a||b|}=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have been working on this for the past week and still can not get the answer. This is dealing with Groups. THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(ab)^{|a||b|}= (a^{|a|}b^{|a|})^{|b|}$           $ = (e b^{|a|}) ^{|b|}$
             $= b^{|a|||b}$
             $= (b^{|b|})^{|a|}$
             $= e^{|a|}$
              $=e$

after the first "=" that is from the fact that $ab=ba$

Comment: I was completely puzzled by this question-until I remembered the absolute value sign in group theory means the order of the element. It's true-if you don't use something for awhile,you lose it.That and the fact the elements commute are the key facts here-I'm not sure,but I think this was given as an exercise in Herstien's classic TOPICS IN ALGEBRA.

Comment: My just for curiosity, if $|a|=|b|=\infty$, would  the proof be exactly the same?

Answer (score 2):

Well, because $a$ and $b$ commute, you can say:
$$ (ab)^{|a||b|} = \underset{|a||b|-times}{\underbrace{ab\cdots ab}} = \underset{|a||b|-times}{\underbrace{a\cdots a}}\cdot\underset{|a||b|-times}{\underbrace{b\cdots b}} = a^{|a||b|}b^{|a||b|} = (a^{|a|})^{|b|}(b^{|b|})^{|a|} = e^{|b|}e^{|a|} = e $$

Answer (score 1):

$(ab)^{|a||b|}=a^{|a||b|}b^{|a||b|}=e$ if $ab=ba$.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion: prove two lemmas before proving the question.

Lemma 1: if $a,b\in G$ and $ab=ba$, then $(a b)^2 = a^2 b^2$.

Lemma 2: if $a,b\in G$ and $ab=ba$, then $\forall k \in \mathbb{N} (ab)^k = a^k b^k$. (Trivially by Induction)

Corollary: $(ab)^{|a||b|} = ((ab)^{|a|})^{|b|} = ((a)^{|a|} (b)^{|a|})^{|b|} = e ((b)^{|a|})^{|b|} = ((b)^{|b|})^{|a|}= e$.